# Best way to Hosting a WebApp inside a WindowsService (Worker Services)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, deployment, windows-services, blazor-server-side

My app is a Windows Service (Worker Services) and I need to add a web app for managing and monitoring tasks of windows service.

```
Product _______ Windows Service
        \______ WebApp
```

For ease of deployment, it is the best if I install only the windows service and the service itself host the web app in a default (but configurable) port. so there is no need to separately deploy a web app.

I use .net technologies and windows platforms (Windows Services, Worker Services, Asp.net Core, Blazor WebApp). what is your suggestion to handle this deployment architecture in .net world.

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to Hosting a WebApp inside a WindowsService (Worker
> Services).
>
> I use .net technologies and windows platforms (Windows Services, Worker
> Services, Asp.net Core, Blazor WebApp). what is your suggestion to
> handle this deployment architecture in .net world

While it's hard to definitively make a final decision because it typically depends on the scenario and requirements. Although, there are couple of way to implement what you are trying to achieve so you have to decide which one mostly suits or meeting your requirements.

Generally, hosting a web app directly inside a Windows service (Worker Service) has some potential benefits, it's generally not recommended for security, maintainability, and scalability reasons.

Thus, keeping above consideration in mind, you could try either of the following way.

First of all, one of the popular approach could be, ASP.NET Core Middleware in Worker Service together, because Integrating ASP.NET Core Middleware into a Worker Service involves incorporating the web app's middleware into the execution pipeline of the Worker Service.

This offers advantages such as increased flexibility, precise control, and potential performance improvements.

For instance, you can directly inject your worker service using middleware DI. Let's consider following example:

```
public class MyWorkerService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IWebHost _webHost;

    public MyWorkerService(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        _webHost = builder.Build();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _webHost.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _webHost.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can register your DI as following:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyWorkerService>();
```

However, drawbacks include a more intricate implementation and the need to manually manage HTTP requests and responses.

**Note:** This approach can be Ideal for Internal management and monitoring apps not exposed to the public internet.

Another way you could consider that is, separating the worker Service and Web App involves deploying the web app independently on IIS or self-hosted using Kestrel.

This approach offers scalability benefits and allows for dedicated security measures for the web app.

However, it has few downsides, including a more complex deployment process and the potential for increased communication overhead between the Worker Service and the web app.

Another good approach can be, separating the ASP.NET Core WebApp or Blazor WebAssembly brings advantages such as clear separation of concerns, dedicated web server features, easier scaling, and standardized security protocols.

But, this approach necessitates distinct deployment and management processes. The choice between ASP.NET Core for versatile web apps and Blazor WebAssembly for single-page applications should be based on specific project requirements and preferences.

**Note:** As said earlier, it's really hard to recommend any specific approach because it completely relies on the scenario, requirement and preferences. You could [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) so that you might get few more ideas also.